# Do I need a setup.cfg if I have a setup.py?

Tags: python, build, setuptools

I use setuptools to build my python package. I was using just a setup.py file, but I added a pyproject.toml in accordance with [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), which appears to have been recently updated to include that file.

What I can't tell from that tutorial or [this one](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html), is whether I need to have a setup.cfg if I'm still using setup.py, and if so, what should be in it. It does show a file tree with both, but then implies that file structure is only indicative with (for people using primarily setup.cfg)

> If you create a setup.py file, this will enable direct interaction with setup.py (which generally should be avoided), and editable installs. This file used to be required, but can be omitted in modern setuptools.

Answer (score 0):

You need not have a setup.cfg file, if you have a setup.py file. One use of setup.cfg is to override the defaults mentioned in setup.py file. If you look at popular libs we still use setup.py file for packaging / distribution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shift to move over to sole use of setup.cfg as it's a safer option. From second [link](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) you provided.

> Transitioning from setup.py to setup.cfg¶
> To avoid executing arbitrary scripts and boilerplate code, we are transitioning into a full-fledged setup.cfg to declare your package information instead of running setup(). This inevitably brings challenges due to a different syntax. Here we provide a quick guide to understanding how setup.cfg is parsed by setuptool to ease the pain of transition.

I believe the functionality is dependent on the version of setuptools that is installed.